# What is wrong with FrameTicks in this small code?

Tags: graphics, output-formatting, ticks, version-7, frame

I'm having a problem with **FrameTicks** not working with this MWE:

```
    t[x_, n_] = (Tanh[(x - n)/2] + Tanh[(x + n)/2])/2;
    r[x_, n_] = (Tanh[(x + n)/2] - Tanh[(x - n)/2])/2;

    ParametricPlot[Table[{r[x, n], t[x, n]}, {n, 0, 3, 0.5}], {x, 0, 10},
    Frame -> True,
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
    FrameTicks ->  {{1/3, 2/3}, {1/3, 2/3}}, (* This line gives me trouble! *)
    GridLines -> {{1/3, 2/3}, {1/3, 2/3}}
    ]
```

So what am I doing wrong here?  I need the FrameTicks to go with the GridLines.  Is this a bug?

Comment: Works perfectly for me.

Comment: Could you include a picture of what you see on your screen? It works for me on v12.2.0 Win7-x64.

Comment: @Syed, I'm getting the proper output, except the FrameTicks aren't drawn and get the error red square around the output.  The error messages window then says there's a wrong directive for the FrameTicks.  I believe this is a bug (I'm using an oooold version of Mma: version 7.  I will upgrade later this year after I buy a new computer).  I'm pretty sure this is a bug with version 7.

Comment: Try: `FrameTicks -> {{{1/3, 2/3}, None}, {{1/3, 2/3}, None}}`

Comment: @Syed, it works!  Thanks a lot!